# Connecting UWP application to sql server database in Azure.

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to connect a UWP  Application to a sql server database that I have already set up via visual studio that's hosted in Azure. I've read that I need a server layer to go this(WCP SERVICE) but I don't understand or know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't go for WCF. WebAPi is the way to go now days. It's pretty broad question.

first you make a database
then a webservice that exposes the right endpoints for your uwp app
then in your uwp app you communicate with the web api via the httpclient.

This looks like a good tutorial to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfnAqfgsvFc

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Apps is the SDK for accessing (with offline sync) SQL data.  Check out http://aka.ms/zumobook which walks you throuhg it.